# $V$ with $ A \subseteq V $ and $V_0 = \bigcap_{V \in \mathcal{V}}V$. If $V_0$ is open than $A$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Say $\mathcal{V}$ the set of all open sets $V$ with $ A \subseteq V $. Say $V_0 = \bigcap_{V \in \mathcal{V}}V$. If $V_0$ is open than $A$ is open.

I wanted to construct rows to proof a contradiction. Say $A$ is closed. Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $A$. Then $x_n$ in $V_0$. But then I get stuck. I want to say that $V_0$ has to be closed and then we have a contradiction.

Can anybody help me to finish my proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that $A$ is $V_0$,  suppose that there exists $x\in V_0$ which is not in $A$, write $V_1=V_0-\{x\}$, $V_1$ contains $A$ and the complementary set of $V_1$ is the union of the complementary space of $V_0$ and $x$, we deduce that it is closed and $V_1$ is open. Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

You can't start from assuming $A$ is closed, closed is not the opposite of open. The opposite of open is "not open".

Instead, you can start from the following hint: If $p\notin A$ then $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{p\})\in \mathcal{V}$.

Answer (score 0):

In any $T_1$ space $X$ we have, for any subset $A \subseteq X$: $$A = \bigcap \{V\mid V \text{ open }, A \subseteq V\}$$

and so the statement is trivialised: your $V_0 = A$.